# How are item level and cypher level related?

Tags: numenera

In Numenera all items have an item level, that determines their use in crafting and other uses, such as which materials can cut certain other materials, and cyphers also have a level, which is randomly rolled and mainly impacts how effective the item is.

Does the cypher level impact the item level at all and vice versa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Numenera practically everything has a level, but there is no such thing as an item level as opposed to a cypher level - a cypher, like a door, like a lock, like an NPC, just has a single level associated with it which is a measure of its power, ability, resilience, what it takes to craft with it, and just about anything else that would require a roll or comparison with an existing value.

Just like a door the level of the cypher indicates the target number required to break it - it is not based on a separate level determined by the material from which the cypher is made.

Note that rolls to find and identify cyphers are not dictated by their level, and have separate rules on page 280 of the Numenera rulebook.

Also for the purposes of crafting, the level of all numenera items should be increased by 5.

Comment: I don't think this is correct, I will update the question.

Comment: @C.Ross Please elaborate as to why you think my answer is incorrect. Have I misinterpreted your question or do you just disagree with my answer?

Comment: I disagree with the answer.  Page 106 and 107 give rules for materials levels.  The simplest Numenera, including Cyphers start at level 5 (see table on 107).  Cyphers commonly have "levels" 1d6, so a minimum of 1.  Level 1 materials are like  Torches.  Obviously Cypher level != material level.

Comment: The values listed in the table on page 107 are not levels - they are the difficulties required to craft the item and are not directly associated with its level. If they were, any character could escape a tied rope, as it would be level 0. Also, in the case of a simple shelter (a difficulty 2 task), the shelter itself could be made of material or materials of any level.

Comment: In the bottom of the second column it lists "Sing stones and firewood" as "level 0 items" a torch as a "level 1 object" and an "arrow or spear" as a "level 2 object".  It defies reason to say that any level 1 Cypher is a level 1 object.

Comment: It also says at the end of the first paragraph on page 106 `Normally, the level of the item
determines the difficulty of creating or repairing it as
well as the time required. For numenera items (cyphers,
artifacts, and oddities), add 5 to the item’s level to
determine the difficulty of creating or repairing it.`

Comment: I have edited my answer to add the above detail about adding 5 to the levels of numenera devices for crafting.